Cascading Boost-buck converters
I am currently designing an ultralow power current source application in which I need to provide positive and negative compliance voltages to a howland current source for symmetric biphasic currents.
This is an ultra-low power application, so I'm using a TI TPS61094 boost converter to bring my 3V battery to 5.5V. Is it possible to run the output of the boost converter into a voltage converter (TL7660) to generate a negative rail or is there something I'm missing here?
A few notes in case it's pertinent.

The TPS61094 is needed as there is a closed loop method to control compliance voltage through a digipot based on output current from the HCS. This is to minimize battery use if lower compliance voltages suffice.
The currents I need to source for the stimulator are at max 1mA, which both parts can easily source.


Yes that is what I'm hoping to do! Thank you and noted on tracing current draws.

Since it is possible to level shift a current source to unipolar, why bipolar biphasic?

The TL7660 seems an odd choice for an "ultralow power" system. Its quiescent current is in the hundreds of μA, orders of magnitude higher than the hundreds of nanoamps of the TPS61094. Something like an LT1617 would make more sense, or some specialized nanopower chip that I'm sure exists but don't know the part number off the top of my head.

I don't see an issue doing this, though I would be very wary of your current draw because for your load, you'd not only have to account for the final output device but also the TL7660 device as well. Something to also note is also the output voltage ripple of your TL7660, so make sure your feedback loop is stable. You can probably use your digipot to help you adjust that stability.
Very interesting application by the way. It sounds like you're making a negative constant voltage source.
